# Python split list before and after specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to split a list into tuples after and before a specific value.

Example

Input:

```
list1 = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
print(some_func(list1, 2))
```

Output:

```
>> [(2,1,1), (1,1,2,1), (1,2,1,1)]
```

[image]

so like I want every tuple to be sliced by the '2' but also keep other values in the tuple. How can I achieve this easily?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the logic for those splits?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't getting the indices then slicing the sublists out work?

Comment: What are the splitting requirements

Comment: Trying to understand the logic here. So for each occurrence of a 2, you want a tuple that contains this 2 and all non-2s that precede and follow it?

Comment: @Thomas yes exactly

Comment: @Jab the value '2' is in some_func() second argument

Comment: @Masklinn idk why but my knowledge of on how to do this without writing 100 lines of code is limited maybe someone would have a better easier solution

Comment: A good start is to find the indices of all the 2s: `[i for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v == 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def split_on(lst, val):
    try:
        # get a tuple between the start of lst and the second occurrence of val
        first_idx = lst.index(val)
        remainder = lst[first_idx + 1:]
        second_idx = remainder.index(val) + (first_idx + 1)
        # and recur with the rest of the list beyond the first occurrence
        return [tuple(lst[:second_idx])] + split_on(remainder, val)
    except ValueError: 
        # base case: there's zero or one occurrences of val, 
        # so we just return the whole lst as a tuple
        return [tuple(lst)]

split_on([2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1], 2)
# [(2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 1)]
```

Note that this is not a terribly *efficient* solution, and for very large lists will start to get pretty slow, since list slicing is kind of expensive as an operation. Something in `itertools` might help with a different, more efficicient approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the indexes of the 2s and then pair each index with the one that is two over to form sub ranges:

```
def neighbors(aList,value):
    indices = [-1] + [i for i,v in enumerate(aList) if v == value] + [len(aList)]
    return [ tuple(aList[s+1:e]) for s,e in zip(indices,indices[2:]) ]

list1 = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]

print(neighbors(list1,2))

[(2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 1)]
```

Note that this will return an empty list if the value is not in aList. You will have to add a condition to return the whole list instead `if len(indices)<3: return [tuple(aList)]` if that's what you want it to do.